# Why is $2\cdot e^{3}$ equal to $40 \cdot 2$ in this integration question?

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

I'm trying to understand an integration question:

$I = \int 2\cdot e^{x}$, given that $I = 50 \cdot 2$ when $x = 3$

I understand the integration, which is:

$I = \int 2\cdot e^{x} = 2e^{x} + C$

However, the next statement is losing me:

$\therefore 50 \cdot 2 = 2e^{3} + c = 40 \cdot 2 + c$

My calculator is showing $e^{3}$ to be $20.085$ so I'm not clear why  $2e^{3}$ is printed in the question as $40 \cdot 2$

Simple explanations will be preferred over more complex explanations.

Comment: Well, your first statement is badly put since: $I=50$ is a number but $\int 2e^x$ is a function. Are there any bounds for the integral you might have forgotten?

Comment: This is very confusing.  Do you maybe mean something like $\int_0^3 2e^t\,dt=50\times 2$?  Why write $50\times 2$ instead of $100$?  Note:  if I have your integral right (not at all clear) then you did the definite integral incorrectly (you left off the lower limit).

Comment: Or did you mean to say something like, Find $F(x)$ given that $F(x)$ is an indefinite integral for $2e^x$ and that $F(3)=100$?

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is unclear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clarity.

Comment: In some places, the dot in $40\cdot2$ is not multiplication but the decimal point.

Comment: I've tried to replicate the question from the [book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Engineering-Mathematics-K-Stroud/dp/0333620224) exactly as it is.  If this is causing experts grief, no wonder it is causing me grief.  I'm going to close this question and step over this question in my book.  Thanks all for the input.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think you have answered this.  It should be a decimal point in the 40.2 and the 50.2.  If you want to provide a formal answer, I will gladly accept.

Comment: A quick look at the text via googlebooks confirms that the author uses a centered dot for the decimal point throughout the book. One key difference is that TeX treats "\cdot" as an operator, putting white space on either side of it, whereas the textbook keeps things closer together: $40{\cdot}2$ vs. $40\cdot2$.

Comment: @BarryCipra thanks, hopefully this should prevent me making similar mistakes later!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the dots in $50\cdot2$ and $40\cdot2$ are to be interpreted not as multiplication but as decimal points. $2e^3$ is (to one decimal place) $40.2$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check well that that is not $$40.2$$ instead of $$40\cdot2.$$ If you're sure after checking that it's the latter, then the only reasonable explanation is that it's a typo.

Also, it's not true that $$2\times e^3=40.2,$$ but I understand if the book is an engineering or physics book. ☺